# Am4Charts Axis renderer draws extra grid line

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I've created a simple XYChart with amcharts4.

I wanted to remove the grid lines on the x-axis, so I've set the stroke opacity for the x-axis grid to 0 with:

```
xAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
```

So far so good, but when data includes a realy small value an extra grid line is drawn. Seems like this line represents the zero value.

Any idea why and how I can hide this line too?

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gypsyycode/pen/OJmodLo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero line is controlled by the `baseGrid` as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Zero_line). You have to disable that one as well:

```
xAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
```